# Taking Output of function and putting it into another function in C

Tags: c, function, input, output

So, I'm trying to put the **output** of one function and put it to another function

Here are the functions that I'm trying to get **output and inputs**, you can just ignore inside of a second function I just simply put `printf` to check if the variables are correct.

```
int guess(int a, int b){
    printf("\nEnter you guess: ");
    scanf("%d,%d", &a, &b);
    return a, b;
}

int check(int a, int b){
    printf("%d %d ",a,b);
}
```

And here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int row, column;
    guess(row, column);
    check(row, column);
}

int guess(int a, int b){
    printf("\nEnter you guess: ");
    scanf("%d,%d", &a, &b);
    return a, b;
}

int check(int a, int b){
    printf("%d %d ",a,b);
}
```

I tried to put it simply to understand how to do it more clearly.

When I **run** the code and put coordinates for example: `4,5` and it only prints out `0 1`

Also, Is it possible to do it with **arrays**?

Comment: FYI a C function (like `guess(...)`) can return _only one_ value. Your statement, `return a, b;` doesn't do what you think it does. The expression `a, b` is a _[comma expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator)_. It evaluates `a` for side effect (there is no side effect, but apparently your compiler doesn't warn you about that), and then it returns the value of `b`.... _Just_ the value of `b`.

Comment: Your implementation of `guess(...)` is pretty far off the mark. It's as if you're trying to learn C by _guessing_ at what the words and symbols mean. I think you will learn faster if you find and follow a good tutorial.

Comment: You wouldn't want to return the result of an input-function directly to a function that uses the values. Why? You cannot use an input-function correctly without ***checking the return***. You must validate against (1) `EOF`; (2) a *matching* or *input* failure or (3) good input ***before*** making use of the values filled by `scanf()`.

Comment: You have two options: 1) return array of int 2) call back functions. Your return type of int implies that you can only return one value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need to use a prototype or declare your functions forward.

2) You can not return 2 variables form a function in C, but you can pass an array and read/write his values:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void guess(int arr[])
{
    printf("\nEnter you guess: ");
    scanf("%d,%d", &arr[0], &arr[1]);
}

void check(int arr[])
{
    printf("%d %d ",arr[0], arr[1]);
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[2];

    guess(arr);
    check(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

or you can pass a reference

```
void guess(int *a, int *b)
{
    printf("\nEnter you guess: ");
    scanf("%d,%d", a, b);
}

guess(&a, &b);
```

Answer (score 1):

The input numbers you read in `guess` functions are actually only read into the local variables `a` and `b`. You'd need to pass pointers to be able to read into the vars in `main`.

Also there's no way to return multiple values from a function in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void guess(int *a, int *b)
{
    printf("\nEnter you guess: ");
    scanf("%d,%d", a, b);
}

int check(int a, int b)
{
    printf("%d %d " ,a, b);
}

int main()
{
    int row = 0, column = 0;
    guess(&row, &column);
    check(row, column);
}
```

You should also check the return value of `scanf` for failures.